# Request not being sent during logout procedure

Tags: javascript, angular, httprequest, jwt, rxjs

I have simplistic Angular2 app, where if user clicks on the

```
<a class="dropdown-item" (click)=authService.logout() href="/welcome">Log out</a>
```

logout menu item, the AuthenticationServices's `logout()` method executes

```
logout() {
  alert('loging out');
  this.authHttp.post(this.endpoint_url + '/auth/logout','').map(res => { 
    if(res.status == 204)  alert('logout successful');
    else alert('logout failed');
  }); 

  this.currentUser = null;
  localStorage.removeItem('token'); 
}
```

the problem is the part

```
  this.authHttp.post(this.endpoint_url + '/auth/logout','').map(res => { 
    if(res.status == 204)  alert('logout successful');
    else alert('logout failed');
  });
```

does not seem to be ever executed. Accessing protected API with `authHttp`(angular2-jwt) works in other parts of application without any problems. 
The first alert "loging out" pops, users is logged out and redirected to "/welcome" and can no longer access private parts of API. However, there is no request to "/auth/logout" in browser nor in server logs.

---

There is also `AuthGuard` service that redirects any non-logged users:

```
canActivate() {
//loggedIn() {!(this.currentUser == null);}
if (!this.auth.loggedIn()) {
  this.router.navigate(['/welcome']);
  return false;
}
return true;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to `subscribe` to observables in order to "fire" them.

```
this.authHttp.post(this.endpoint_url + '/auth/logout','').subscribe((res)=>{
    if(res.status == 204){  
     alert('logout successful');
     this.currentUser = null;
     localStorage.removeItem('token');
   }else {alert('logout failed');}           
});
```

And if you need to remove the token after the logout is successfull you need to do this inside the functions callback (`subscribe`).

Comment: Yes, it helped(partially), along with other answer (canceling the click event). Now it executes, but after the token was removed(and thus failing).

Comment: Oh you want token to be removed afterwards? Check my updated answer. You can remove the token inside the res.status == 204 or wherever you like inside the subscribe

Comment: Turns out the other problem was on server side, coupled with mis-configured jwt (which appeared to be working because of another error in other component). All to the original problem was not using `subscribe`. Also, I should *not* cancel the event.

Comment: @wondra ah, glad you figured it out.